# How to perform GET/POST request using OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, exact-online

Am using [omniauth-exact gem](https://github.com/NicolasKramer/omniauth-exact) to authenticate the user to [ExactOnline](https://start.exactonline.nl), it works perfectly good but after authenticating the user I also need to query back to [ExactAPI](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResources.aspx?SourceAction=10) and fetch some data which in case am supposed to use either `GET,POST` method.

The `callback` returns back users info, `token` and `refresh token` so I need to use access token to request data from Exactonline API using `omniauth`. How can i archive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OmniAuth is really just a tool for authenticating the user. If you want to perform some actions against the api which are not really part of the authentication flow you would normally save the access token and use it with an API client.

You can get the token in the handler which handles the Omniauth callbacks:

```
class class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def exact
    auth_hash = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    session[:token] = auth_hash[:credentials][:token]
    # ... 
  end
def
```

For the providers like Twitter or Facebook there are ready made API clients but in this case you may want to use [Intridea's generic OAuth2 library](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) to create a client.

```
require 'oauth2'
client = OAuth2::Client.new('client_id', 'client_secret', site: 'https://start.exactonline.nl/api')
access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, session[:token])
response = access_token.post('/api/v1/something', { foo: :bar })

case response.status
when 201:
  # ...
when 401:
  # ... 
end
```

I would encourage you to create a client class or a service object to handle this - don't inline it into your controller as its really messy and hard to test properly.

Here are a few examples of existing API clients:

- https://github.com/sferik/twitter
- https://github.com/hanklords/flickraw